# How to send values from Arduino to Android through WiFi?

Tags: android, arduino, wifi

Is it possible? Please help me out with some codes.

I would like to get status updates from my Arduino to know and display LED status if its ON/OFF through WiFi.

Comment: I think you need some hardware AND some software...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would've posted this as a comment on the other answer but I can't yet.

You could make a TCP server with your Arduino, and then check the status on your Android code.
I'm assuming you already have a [WiFi](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield)/[Ethernet](http://arduino.cc/es/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield) shield on your Arduino. Without one of them there's no way to do this.

Here's a good [example code](http://www.lauridmeyer.com/2012/04/simple-arduino-tcp-server-using-the-ethernetshield-and-a-java-client/) with Java and Arduino. The results will only be available in your local network unless you do some port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

I dont got some example Code for you, but i've got some keywords/ideas for you.

You could run an small embedded HTTP server on the Arduino with it's own IP Address.
Or some type of other server via TCP or UDP.

Then simply request data (eg. Status of the LED) within the Android application (HTTP client) where the Arduino has to answer.

Comment: i'll start with that i guess. ,until there's a simplier aproach..thanks!